# Is there a bug in python's (2.7) documentation on default comparison?

Tags: python, comparison, nonetype

This is a question about unclear documentation.

Consider the following example code:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('eq')

f = Foo()

result = None <= f
print result
>>> True
```

The official documentation says:

> If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined, class instances are compared by object identity (“address”).

`Foo` implements `__eq__`, so according to the documentation, the default strategy of comparing object id should not be invoked. I'm guessing that, in fact, comparison of object id is exactly what's going on, and that the documentation is buggy. Is this correct?

Should the documentation say

> If `__cmp__()` would be invoked but is not defined, then the two objects are compared by their ids.

?

Comment: You’re right; congratulations.

Comment: @minitech: Is that sarcasm? I can't tell if you're actually suggesting that this is a documentation bug. If so I will report.

Comment: No, but I’m not sure what else to say. It’s not really much of a bug, and it’s gone in Python 3, since `__cmp__` doesn’t exist. Strictly speaking, it’s not wrong, since it doesn’t say “if and only if”. =)

Comment: @minitech: Indeed. It is confusing, however.

Comment: Your `__eq__` is called for `None == f`, but not for `<=` or `>=', `__le__` and `__ge__` not being implemented in your class. If you define `__le__` and `__ge__` they will be called for the corresponding operator. The documentation still seems wrong though.

Comment: @mhawke: Yes, I understand that `__eq__` won't do anything for eg. <=. As I said in the OP, the documentation suggests otherwise, which is why I asked if the documentation is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because The `None` have not define `__le__` method:

```
class Foo(object):
        def __eq__(self, other):
            print('eq')

f = Foo()

test1 = None
id( test1 )
id( f )
test1 <= f # id( test1 ) <= id( f ), equals to test1.__le__(f), output  True in my machine
```